# How can I change the Lua version of the local console in ZeroBrane Studio?

Tags: zerobrane

I already know how to change the version of the Lua interpreter by going to the menu-option
"Project -> Lua Interpreter".

I see the confirmation by executing a Lua-file containing the line `print(_VERSION)`, which outputs the set version e.g. `Lua 5.3`.

However, when I type `_VERSION` into the "Local console" I still get `"Lua 5.1"`.

Any advice on how to change the Lua version of the local console as well?

Answer (score 1):

The Local console uses the same interpreter that runs the IDE itself, so it's not possible to change at this time. There is a [ticket open](https://github.com/pkulchenko/ZeroBraneStudio/issues/490) that could enable support for other Lua versions, but it hasn't been implemented yet.

As a simple workaround you can start normal/remote debugging with the selected interpreter (Lua 5.3, for example) and run all the commands you need in that environment (in the Remote Console).